# How i filter fluentD logs on kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, kubernetes, fluentd, efk

My kubernetes have liveness enable, and it log on application, like this:

```
kubectl logs -n example-namespace example-app node-app
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:12:19 +0000] "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 301 175
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:19 +0000] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3104
::192.168.0.1    - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:19 +0000] "GET /home-page HTTP/1.1" 200 3104
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:19 +0000] "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 301 175
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:22 +0000] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3104
```

I Use fluentD to send logs to ClowdWatch.
My fluentD configuration:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-container-insights/latest/k8s-deployment-manifest-templates/deployment-mode/daemonset/container-insights-monitoring/quickstart/cwagent-fluentd-quickstart.yaml

How can i filter, to fluentD only matches

::192.168.0.1    - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:19 +0000] "GET /home-page HTTP/1.1" 200 3104

And ignore

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:13:19 +0000] "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 301 175

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, i found this solution:

```
<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**_kube-system_**>
  @type null
</match>
```

and this

```
  <filter **>
   @type grep
   exclude1 log docs
  </filter>
```

The reference:

https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter/issues/91

https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/grep

EDIT

or add:

```
      exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*", "/var/log/containers/fluentd*", "/var/log/containers/*istio*"]
```

this config ignore the source files with pattern *istio*.